# can't start "store listing experimence" in other languages from google play console

Tags: google-play, google-play-console

I simply want to test the attraction of a new Icon for my app in google play. 
My App supports 5 languages also in "Store presence".

For this I have created a "store listing experiment" for icon, which was stright forward and works.

But there is a note at the bottom of the test saying:

> Note: this experiment is not being served to users who view your store
>   listing in the following languages: de-DE, es-ES, fr-FR, it-IT Find
>   out more.

I am asking here because:
- I searched the hole internet for this, but I didnt find any explanation.
- The Link "Find out more", provides only informations, which are clear anyway, but nothing about my issue.
- Contacting google is inpossible. I have no clue where to contact support, whith non default question wizard.

Comment: I have the same problem here. Just a question: Have you ever run a "Localized" A/B experiment before?

Comment: No I havent ...